# Javascript - Find Index of array element using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am new to using recursion so I just want to know, if I want to know the index of an array element, by using recursion (Javascript). Is this the right way, or there is a better way?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function search(arr, item) {
    const searchIndex = (array, elem, index = 0) => {
        if (array.length === 0) return -1
        if (array[0] === elem) return index
        return searchIndex(array.slice(1), elem, ++index)
    }

    return searchIndex(arr, item)
}
console.log(search(arr, 4)) // output should be 3
```

Comment: Yeah, it calls itself until conditions tell it to stop, mazel tov.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the arguments a bit and add index and hand over the complete array.

```js
function search(array, item, i = 0) {
    if (i >= array.length) return -1;
    if (array[i] === item) return i;
    return search(array, item, i + 1);
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(search(arr, 4)) // 3
console.log(search(arr, 8)) // -1
console.log(search([], 4)) // -1
```

An approach without an additional variable, but with slicing the array.

```js
function search(array, item) {
    if (!array.length) return -1;
    if (array[0] === item) return 0;
    return search(array.slice(1), item) + 1 || -1;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(search(arr, 1)) // 0
console.log(search(arr, 2)) // 1
console.log(search(arr, 3)) // 2
console.log(search(arr, 4)) // 3
console.log(search(arr, 5)) // 4
console.log(search(arr, 8)) // -1
console.log(search([], 4)) // -1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is incorrect on several levels:

## It reinvents the wheel

```
yourarray.indexOf(youritem)
```

is already doing what you need.

## It chooses the wrong approach

Recursion is a possible option while you are coding, but you should be absolutely sure that you need recursion when you consider using it. It tends to overcomplicate your code and since each function call is stored in a memory section called the stack, you may end up having a stack overflow error (no pun intended).

If you wanted to do it manually, then you could do something like this:

```
function findIndex(array, item) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] === item) return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

## It overcomplicates the solution

You will have trouble when you need to make any modification on your functionality. Your code needs to be as clear as possible.

## Possibilities of performance issues

If you reimplement a functionality that already exists, you need to conduct many stress tests to find out whether your implementation is at least as good as the original one.

---

A recursive solution, just for fun, but don't use this in real-life:

```
function findIndex(array, item, index) {
    if (index === array.length) return -1;
    else if (array[index] === item) return index;
    else return findIndex(array, item, index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `indexOf` function for this purpose:

```
const arr = ['1', '2', '3','4']
  
  const index = arr.indexOf('4');
  console.log(index)
  
  //index is `3`
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: The question asks for recursion, which this answer does not do.